# Writing onto text file, whenever I add to line, it is written on the next line

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that adds players scores onto a text file in this format:

```
John    3    4                (The name and scores are seperated by "\t")
Bob     3    6                    (Each new name has it's own line)
```

So the problem is that if I have user "Bob" under the line carrying "John" and I use my program for "John" it would create a new line and then "\t"+str(score), whereas I want it to be added on the same line. So let's say John scored a 3 this time, the text file would write:

```
John    3    4
                  3Bob     3    6
```

instead of:

```
John    3    4    3
Bob     3    6
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
r = open("Class%d.txt"%(group),"r")
lines = r.readlines()
r.close()
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if name in line:
        lines[i] = line + "\t" + str(score)
        break
else:
    lines.append("\n" + name + "\t" + str(score))
w = open("Class%d.txt"%(group),"w")
w.writelines(lines)
w.close()
```

Is it something wrong with the placement of the "\n"? Thanks for any help given!

Comment: have you considered using csv instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is occurring because `.readlines()` retains the newlines at the end of each line. As an alternative, you can read the file data into a single string and split it into lines using `.splitlines()`, which by default throws away the newlines (although you can pass it a `keepends` argument of `True` to keep the newlines, if you want).

Using splitlines(), your code becomes something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

fname = "student_data"

r = open(fname, "r")
lines = r.read()
r.close()

lines = lines.splitlines()

name, score = "John", 3
name = name + "\t"

for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if name in line:
        lines[i] = line + "\t" + str(score)
        break
else:
    lines.append(name + str(score))

#for s in lines: print s

lines = '\n'.join(lines)

w = open(fname, "w")
w.write(lines)
w.close()
```

Your data file is a text file but it does not end in a newline; that can cause problems with some text editors and other text-processing tools. You may consider changing that.

---

**Update**

I've modified the code to add a tab (`\t`) to the end of the name. So now new scores won't be incorrectly added to a name that happens to contain the new name. Eg, if there's a line for Alexander in the file and the new name is Alex, then Alex's data will go onto a new line since `"Alex\t"` is not in `"Alexander\t"`.

Answer (score 0):

`readlines` return lines **with their `\n`**

I would modify this line:

```
    if name in line:
        lines[i] = line.strip() + "\t" + str(score) + "\n"
```

`strip` makes sure there's no `\n` or `\t` at the end of your line.