# Writing onto file, If exact name is in line then... Else

Tags: python

Here is the part of my program which firstly reads a file, checking if the "name" which the user would give is in the file, if it is, then it would add onto the line, but if it isn't then it would start a new line.

```
r = open("Class%s.txt"%(group),"r")
lines = r.readlines()
r.close()
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if name in line:
            lines[i] = line.strip() + "\t" + str(score) + "\n"
            break
else:
    lines.append("\n" + name + "\t" + str(score))
w = open("Class%s.txt"%(group),"w")
w.writelines(lines)
w.close()
```

The problem I have with this program is that if a user named "Alexander" uses the program before a user named "Alex" does so, the program would write "Alex"'s score on the same line as "Alexander"'s as it searches each line for the characters "Alex" and not if it is the EXACT match. Thanks for any help given!

Comment: It is 3rd question for same problem. Would you have given the exact format of the line is would already be solved. Without the format we only use what you give : *the string is in the line* or *the string is in the file* which is not precise enough. Unless you say what the format is **exactly** you will only get uncomplete answers (except by chance).

Comment: You can solve this by splitting lines, as suggested below, but you don't need to do that. Since the fields on each line are tab-separated you can simply add a tab to the end of the name you're searching for. I won't add an answer here, I'll just update [my answer to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28515355/4014959).

Answer (score 0):

I presume each line looks like

```
Alexander 25 31 19 16
```

I suggest comparing like

```
if name.lower() == line.split(None, 1)[0].lower():
```

(compare against the line's first word, and ignore capitalization).

Comment: or __line.partition(' ')[0]__

Comment: @volcano: note that `str.split()` will split on any contiguous whitespace - any combination of `" \t\r\n"` - rather than on exactly `" "`.

Comment: Did not think about it. But ff the delimiter are spaces - partition is much faster

Answer (score -4):

Just change

```
if name in line:
```

with

```
if name in line.strip():
```

This way you'll look into a list of words, not a list of characters. And you'll match complete words.

Comment: This does not fix the main problem; `Alex` will still match `Alexander`.

Comment: Maybe you meant `if name in line.split()`?